# Unable to add an IF statement to SQL query

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

This is my query that works:

```
Select AsOfDate, Family, Type, DocID, Title, Date1, Date2, Date3, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3
FROM DocumentationData
WHERE Type = @Type 
AND Family = @Family
AND AsOfDate = (SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                       FROM DocumentationData
                       WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate )
```

I want to add a condition. I want an additional constraint of Usage = 'Active" if @ActiveOnly is true.

This is what I am trying, but it results in an error:

```
Select AsOfDate, Family, Type, DocID, Title, Date1, Date2, Date3, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3
FROM DocumentationData
WHERE Type = @Type 
AND Family = @Family
AND AsOfDate = (IF (@ActiveOnly = 'TRUE')
                BEGIN
                SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                FROM DocumentationData
                WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                AND Usage = 'Active'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                FROM DocumentationData
                WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                END
               )
```

Comment: Error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this without using `IF...THEN...ELSE`.  You were close w/ your first query attempt, just apply similar `IF` logic using additional clauses to the `WHERE` in your subquery.

```
SELECT AsOfDate, Family, Type, DocID, Title, Date1, Date2, Date3, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3
  FROM DocumentationData
 WHERE Type = @Type 
   AND Family = @Family
   AND AsOfDate =  (SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                      FROM DocumentationData
                     WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                       AND ( ( @ActiveOnly = 'TRUE' AND Usage = 'Active') 
                             OR (@ActiveOnly <> 'TRUE') 
                           )
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a THEN in there.

```
AND AsOfDate =  IF (@ActiveOnly = 'TRUE') 
                THEN                 
                SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                FROM DocumentationData
                WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                AND Usage = 'Active'

                ELSE
                BEGIN
                SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                FROM DocumentationData
                WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate

                END IF
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Ok, I updated it a bit.  Kinda going off the top of my head, but give that a shot.

Comment: Can't remember in SQL is it == for comparison instead of = ?

Comment: comparison for SQL is `=` not `==`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other options, I found that copying the whole thing into two queries like this works:

```
IF(@ActiveOnly = 'TRUE')
BEGIN
Select AsOfDate, Family, Type, DocID, Title, Date1, Date2, Date3, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3
FROM DocumentationData
WHERE Type = @Type 
AND Family = @Family
AND AsOfDate =  (SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                      FROM DocumentationData
                      WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                      AND Usage = 'Active'
                      )
END                          
ELSE
BEGIN
Select AsOfDate, Family, Type, DocID, Title, Date1, Date2, Date3, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3
FROM DocumentationData
WHERE Type = @Type 
AND Family = @Family
AND AsOfDate =  (SELECT Max(AsOfDate)
                          FROM DocumentationData
                          WHERE AsOfDate <= @CurrentDate
                          )
END
```